# What kind of array declaration is this ? "1/(A10:Z10>0)"

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I found in an Excel equation, an input for array for Lookup_vector like this "1/(A10:Z10>0)", which returns an array[26] of "1" and/or "!DIV/0" depend on the value in each cell in A10:Z10 (where cell is number > 0 or text then 1; negative number or blank cell then !DIV/0). This kind of array declaration is very strange to me, can someone please give some more insight about this type of array declaration?

Thanks!

Comment: Lookup then looks through that resulting array to find what you want.  My guess is the value it is looking for is `2` and since 2 is greater than `1` it will return the location of the last time that the number in that row is greater than `0`.  Not sure what else you want, you already know it returns an array of `1`s and `#Div/0` errors.  The error are ignored and the lookup will look through the array.  If you lookup `1` in that array it will return the first location where it is greater than `0`

Comment: Hi Scott, yes, your guess is totally correct, the Lookup_value is 2 so that lookup function returns the ref of last time number in array greater than 0. My point was about the way to declare this kind of array "a/(range>0)", does it have a name, where can I read more about this ?! or this is something only be obtained through experience :) thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi Scott, got it, thanks! I've tried with "a*(range>0)", "a+(range>0)", "a-(range>0)" and be clearer now. It turns out that (range>0) will return 1 or 0 depend on value in the cell. So I think the way to declare an array "a/(range>0)" is smart, and likely from experience.